# Unresolved external symbol __Atomic_fetch_add_4 referenced from LIBCMTD.lib

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, msvcrt

I've just installed the VS2012 beta, and upgraded my VS2010 project, it seems to compile as it should, but when linking, I get the following errors:

> 1>LIBCMTD.lib(excptptr.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external
>   symbol __Atomic_fetch_add_4 referenced in function "unsigned long
>   __cdecl std::_Inc_atomic_counter_explicit(unsigned long &,enum std::memory_order)"
>   (?_Inc_atomic_counter_explicit@std@@YAKAAKW4memory_order@1@@Z)
>   1>LIBCMTD.lib(excptptr.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external
>   symbol __Atomic_fetch_sub_4 referenced in function "unsigned long
>   __cdecl std::_Dec_atomic_counter_explicit(unsigned long &,enum std::memory_order)"
>   (?_Dec_atomic_counter_explicit@std@@YAKAAKW4memory_order@1@@Z)

Google has no reference to these error messages, which is surprising.
It looks as if `__Atomic_fetch_add_4` should be an intrinsic for the fetchadd4 op-code, but it's not (as far as I can tell), the proper intrinsic is `_InterlockedIncrement`.

I have no idea what could be causing this. Interestingly it comes from `excptptr.obj`, and I have C++ exceptions disabled in this project. Enabling them made no difference.

Edit:
I notice when googling that this symbol only appears to be referenced by GNU code. Perhaps MS have updated the STL for VS2012 and pulled in some GNU reference code that hasn't been caught yet; needs to be changed to use the MS intrinsic?

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem with a project of mine which was compiled in VS2010 and getting the  unresolved external symbol __Atomic_fetch_add_4  error when compiled in VS2012. 
I couldn't figure out why it was happening but after a "clean solution" and "rebuild all" the problem went away. I suspect there where old obj files lying around that caused the problem.